Coinbase Advance Trading API returns "Error: account not available" when placing orders
For the past while I have been trying to get this crypto trading bot to work.  The problem is that while I can get/list accounts when I place an order I get a 400 error.
The code:
def place_order(symbol, side, amount, price=None):
    url = 'https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/orders'
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+encryption_build.build_jwt(
            'POST api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/orders',
            api_key,
            api_secret),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    client_order_id = uuid.uuid4()
    try:
        # Order details
        order_data = {
          "client_order_id": str(client_order_id),
          "product_id": symbol,
          "side": side,
          "order_configuration": {
            "market_market_ioc": {
              "base_size": str(amount)
            }
          },
          "retail_portfolio_id": "41864a16-1fd4-50bb-a633-278d9c39f846"
        }
        res = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(order_data))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

place_order('BTC-USD',  'SELL', amount=0.01)

The response:
{
    "error":"INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "error_details":"account is not available",
    "message":"account is not available"
}

The API key has view/trade permissions.  The List Accounts endpoint returns my accounts on Coinbase.  A BTC and fiat account in CAD are present.  Both are active.  Specifying the retail portfolio, or using other libraries to do this didn't make a difference.
I expect a 200 status code with the order pending or filled on Coinbase's end.
EDIT: Running it through Postman produced the same error.
POST https://api.coinbase.com/api/v3/brokerage/orders
400
111 ms
POST /api/v3/brokerage/orders HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Im9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbnMvNjUwYjZhYjEtMTk2My00ZTQ1LThhYWMtNmUyYTdkNGU0MmQxL2FwaUtleXMvOTg0ZTE4ZjMtZDEzZi00NjllLTk3ZDItNTNkZDEzYzM1NDJhIiwibm9uY2UiOiJlODE3MmZmZDZjMzQ3ZDdhNzRjZDk3YWFlNmJkZTEzZTYyZWY5ZTk3ZjEyZTBlOTU4NTgwNzMyMzUwZTBlMmFiIiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJzdWIiOiJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25zLzY1MGI2YWIxLTE5NjMtNGU0NS04YWFjLTZlMmE3ZDRlNDJkMS9hcGlLZXlzLzk4NGUxOGYzLWQxM2YtNDY5ZS05N2QyLTUzZGQxM2MzNTQyYSIsImlzcyI6ImNkcCIsIm5iZiI6MTcyMDU2MTE2MSwiZXhwIjoxNzIwNTYxMjgxLCJ1cmkiOiJQT1NUIGFwaS5jb2luYmFzZS5jb20vYXBpL3YzL2Jyb2tlcmFnZS9vcmRlcnMifQ.0ECu5nM8XTTLv7caGPxSBmoVUDoqW-z07z4Jz8wDljjIf2rreGjZ-L-ZAzMcDMU8FafSEQeo81FExUkUe2TVww
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.39.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 9506a059-e326-402b-8a4f-7aefcba39eaf
Host: api.coinbase.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 231
Cookie: __cf_bm=wG1twa3RotRq8PB5plk5UPsC8Luskeyddh9famNqHE4-1720561189-1.0.1.1-lWThs07H99ZxAB78K2ZUdY.4aDP0LEg49rLxEqPyrbL2ivpjLLQFKbsSMcieMCZ.eVdyusgBCyVspRfrdP.5LQ; cb_dm=16c8bf71-6e14-4c79-8c05-83251661ce3b
 
{"client_order_id": "b372a61a-7585-4dd1-bb6c-f5990967412b", "product_id": "BTC-USD", "side": "BUY", "order_configuration": {"market_market_ioc": {"base_size": "0.01"}}, "retail_portfolio_id": "d641518f-dd81-49fc-96d1-ce1e782f697f"}
 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2024 21:40:17 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 108
Connection: keep-alive
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Accept, Second-Factor-Proof-Token, Client-Id, Access-Token, X-Cb-Project-Name, X-Cb-Is-Logged-In, X-Cb-Platform, X-Cb-Session-Uuid, X-Cb-Pagekey, X-Cb-Ujs, Fingerprint-Tokens, X-Cb-Device-Id, X-Cb-Version-Name
access-control-allow-methods: GET,POST,DELETE,PUT
access-control-allow-private-network: true
access-control-expose-headers:
access-control-max-age: 7200
Cache-Control: no-store
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
trace-id: 7311873497407553797
trace-id: 7311873497407553797
vary: Origin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
x-download-options: noopen
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 51
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 8a0b78b7bf7caca0-YYZ
 
{"error":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","error_details":"account is not available","message":"account is not available"}

There is very little on this on the internet.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

can you execute the same with an api client?  curl postman insomnia?  try there first, then you can debug your code if that works

I ran it through Postman and got the same response.  I've updated my question accordingly.
